# Generic match function for discriminated union types in Typescript

Tags: generics, typescript, typescript2.1

Is it possible to define something like a generic match function over discriminated union type?
Let's say we have the following type definitions:

```
const Kinds = {
  A: 'A',
  B: 'B',
};
type Kind = typeof Kinds.A | typeof Kinds.B;
type Value = A | B;
interface A {
  kind: Kinds.A
}
interface B {
  kind: Kinds.B
}
```

With switch statement it is possible to define match function like:

```
interface Matcher<T> {
  Kinds.A: (value: A) => T
  Kinds.B: (value: B) => T
}
function match<T>(matcher: Matcher<T>) {
  return function(value: Value) {
    switch (value.kind) {
      case Kinds.A: return matcher[Kinds.A](value);
      case Kinds.B: return matcher[Kinds.B](value);
    }
  }
}
```

It does the job, but it is very tedious to define such functions especially when one have many union members.

Is it possible to simplify this definition somehow, maybe with [Mapped Types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12114) or other existing means from the latest 2.1 branch.

I was playing around with "Mapped Types", but I'm not sure that it is actually possible to get concrete **Value** even when I know **Kind**, e.g something like:

```
type Matcher<T> = {[P in Kind]: (value: P) => T};
function match<T>(matcher: Matcher<T>) {
  return function(value: Value) {
    return matcher[value.kind](value);
  }
}
```

but where one can actually translate **P** to corresponding **Value** type.

Answer (score 1):

The key to this is being able to get a member of a union based on its kind.  That can be done with a type like this:

```
type UnionMemberByKind<K> = Extract<Union, { kind: K }>
```

`Extract<T, U>` returns the members of `T` that match `U`: in this case it's going to return the single member of the union with the specified `kind`.

With that type, you can properly build your matcher object:

```
type Matcher<Res> = {
    [P in Union["kind"]]: (value: UnionMemberByKind<P>) => Res
}
```

And then define your match function basically as before:

```
function match<T>(matcher: Matcher<T>) {
    return function(value: Union) {
        return matcher[value.kind](value as any);
    }
}
```

(The `as any` cast is unfortunate, but I can't find a way to avoid it)